# Контекст равен null в AsyncTask'е во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Хочу что бы при пересоздании Activity не исчезал DialogProgress со статусом выполняемого AsyncTask'а. Для этого AsyncTask вызываю во фрагменте с setRetainInstance(true).
ProgressDialog создаётся в классе AsyncTask'а в onPreExecute. При вызове progress=new ProgressDialog(activity.get()) появляется ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

Код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.counter)TextView counter;
private MyAsyncTask2 task;
private static final String MyFragment="MyFragment";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.progressDialogButton)
public void showProgressDialog(){
    Log.d("happy","showProgressDialog()");
    task=new MyAsyncTask2(MainActivity.this);
    task.execute();
}

@OnClick(R.id.progressFragmentDialogButton)
public void showFragmentProgressDialog(){
    FragmentTaskWrapper myFragment=(FragmentTaskWrapper)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyFragment);
    if(myFragment==null){
        myFragment=new FragmentTaskWrapper();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(myFragment,MyFragment).commit();
    }
    myFragment.startProgress();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(task!=null)task.cancel(false);
}
```

}

Код FragmentTaskWrapper

```
public class FragmentTaskWrapper extends Fragment {

private MyAsyncTask2 task;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.d("happy","FragmentTaskWrapper - onCreate");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("happy","FragmentTaskWrapper - onCreateView");
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    Log.d("happy","FragmentTaskWrapper - onAttach");
    super.onAttach(context);
    task.setActivity((MainActivity)getActivity());
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    task.setActivity(null);
}

public void startProgress(){
    Log.d("happy","FragmentTaskWrapper - startProgress");
    task=new MyAsyncTask2((MainActivity)getActivity());
    task.execute();
}
```

}

Код MyAsyncTask2

```
public class MyAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

private WeakReference<MainActivity>activity;
private ProgressDialog progress;

public MyAsyncTask2(MainActivity activity) {
    Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - constructor");
    this.activity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
}

public void setActivity(MainActivity activity){
    if (activity!=null){
        this.activity=new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }
    else{
        this.activity=null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - onPreExecute");
    if (activity!=null){
        Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - onPreExecute IF activity != null");
        progress=new ProgressDialog(activity.get());
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setTitle("Progress Dialog");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.setMax(9);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - doInBackground");
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        publishProgress(i);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - onProgressUpdate");
    progress.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    Log.d("happy","MyAsyncTask2 - onPostExecute");
    if (progress!=null){
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

NPE в классе MyAsyncTask2 в методе onPreExecute

```
progress=new ProgressDialog(activity.get());
```

Замена на activity.get().getApplicationContext() не даёт эффекта, тот же NPE.
Логирующие сообщения в проовераденных методах фрагмента и AsyncTask'a выводятся в следующем порядке:

- FragmentTaskWrapper - startProgress
- MyAsyncTask2 - constructor
- MyAsyncTask2 - onPreExecute
- MyAsyncTask2 - onPreExecute IF activity != null

Т.е. у фрагмента вообще не вызываются методы

- onCreate
- onCreateView (проверрадил тоже, хоть тут headless-фрагмент без
  разметки, по илее этот метод вообще никак не нужен)
- onAttach

а сразу вызывается startProgress. Не понимаю в итоге как вообще этот фрагмент заработал.
Далее в AsyncTask'е отдельная проверка на null поля activity проходит в методе onPreExecute но далее из этого поля не могу достать контекст.

Почитал про фрагменты поподробнее, да, написано что пока не выполнятся методы onCreate (и/или onCreateView?) этого фрагмента "не существует".

Но как тогда в AsyncTask'е Activity не равна null?
И главное как передать активити или контекст в AsyncTask что бы ProgressDialog можно было создать?

Comment: Я боролся с аналогичной ошибкой, возникавшей при повороте экрана с бегущим прогресс баром. Не поборол и тупо заблокировал поворот экрана пока не закончится `AsyncTask` - буду с интересом следить :)

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) есть реализация того, что Вы хотите сделать. Попробуйте, может так получится.

Comment: Получилось @Barmaley https://youtu.be/cIMwRSseW_E https://github.com/Arvalon/ProgressDialog В общих чертах необходимо было добавить пару методов public void hideProgress(){
        progress.dismiss();
    }

    public void showProgress(){
        progress.show();
    } и ещё проверять завершился таск иил нет